# Remove all href 'wrapper' except href contains specific value: PHP

Tags: php, filter, preg-replace

**content:**

```
<a href="http://www.lipsum.com/">Lorem Ipsum</a> is simply dummy text 
of the printing and typesetting industry. 
<a href="http://www.google.com/1111/2222/3333">Lorem Ipsum</a> has been the industrys 
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer 
took a <a href="http://gallery.com">galley</a> of type and scrambled 
it to make a type specimen <a href="http://www.google.com/1111/3333/4444">book</a>.
```

**Content includes 3 "a href" link**

```
http://www.lipsum.com/
http://www.google.com/1111/2222/3333
http://www.google.com/1111/3333/4444
http://gallery.com/
```

**I want this result:** Selected href value is `href="http://google.com/1111/3333****` only

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
specimen <a href="http://www.google.com/1111/3333/4444">book</a>.
```

**Does anybody know how to do this? Hope you can understand the question. Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing/transforming *HTML* content with regular expressions is not good idea.
But for your small fragment and considering that you need to preserve a *link* text while deleting itself (e.g. `"Lorem Ipsum"`) you may use the following `preg_replace` solution:

```
$html = '<a href="http://www.lipsum.com/">Lorem Ipsum</a> is simply dummy text 
of the printing and typesetting industry. 
<a href="http://www.google.com/1111/2222/3333">Lorem Ipsum</a> has been the industrys 
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer 
took a <a href="http://gallery.com">galley</a> of type and scrambled 
it to make a type specimen <a href="http://www.google.com/1111/3333/4444">book</a>.';

$re = '/<a href="http:\/\/(?!www\.google\.com\/1111\/3+\/[^>]+).*?>([^<>]+)<\/a>/m';
$result = preg_replace($re, "$1", $html);

echo $result;
```

The output:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys 
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer 
took a galley of type and scrambled 
it to make a type specimen <a href="http://www.google.com/1111/3333/4444">book</a>.
```

---

`(?!www\.google\.com\/1111\/3+\/[^>]+)` - lookahead negative assertion, matches links, those `href` attribute value doesn't fit the needed requirement `href="http://www.google.com/1111/3333****`

**----------**

The more accurate way would be using ***DOMDocument***/***DOMXpath*** classes:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query("//a[not(contains(@href, 'http://www.google.com/1111/3333'))]");
foreach ($nodes as $n) {
    $n->parentNode->replaceChild($dom->createTextNode($n->nodeValue), $n);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
```

The output:

```
<html><body>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys 
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer 
took a galley of type and scrambled 
it to make a type specimen <a href="http://www.google.com/1111/3333/4444">book</a>.</body></html>
```